# Существует ли способ вывести iconCaption вместе со своей картинкой у метки?

Tags: javascript, yandex-maps-api, яндекс-карты

Мне нужно заменить внешний вид метки на свою картинку + сделать к ней подпись.

Вот [пример из песочницы](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsbox/2.1/icon_customImage).
Здесь заменяется внешний вид метки на любую картинку. Однако мне нужно, чтобы вместе с картинкой работала и подпись. Если немного изменить код в песочнице, то подпись появится. Однако пропадёт картинка. Но если раскомментить опцию iconLayout, то пропадает подпись.

Существует ли способ вывести iconCaption вместе со своей картинкой метки?

```js
ymaps.ready(function () {
    var myMap = new ymaps.Map('map', {
            center: [55.751574, 37.573856],
            zoom: 9
        }, {
            searchControlProvider: 'yandex#search'
        }),
        myPlacemark = new ymaps.Placemark(myMap.getCenter(), {
            hintContent: 'Собственный значок метки',
            balloonContent: 'Это красивая метка',
            iconCaption: 'test',
            iconContent: 'test'
        }, {
            // Опции.
            // Необходимо указать данный тип макета.
            //>>>>> iconLayout: 'default#image',
            // Своё изображение иконки метки.
            iconImageHref: 'images/myIcon.gif',
            iconImageSize: [30, 42],
            iconImageOffset: [-5, -38],
            preset: 'islands#blueCircleDotIconWithCaption'
        });

    myMap.geoObjects.add(myPlacemark);
});
```

Думаю, нужно как-то создать свой пресет для оформления метки или выбрать наиболее подходящий из стандартных. Только вот на [странице документации](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/doc/jsapi/2.0/dg/concepts/geoobjects-docpage) при переходе на страницу с описанием стандартных пресетов возвращается 404.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Кроме `iconLayout: 'default#image'`, существует ещё [default#imageWithContent](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/doc/jsapi/2.1/ref/reference/Placemark-docpage/#param-options), которая как раз таки и отвечает за пользовательское изображение иконки с содержимым.

Помимо этого, есть  возможность создавать [свои макеты](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/doc/jsapi/2.1/dg/concepts/layouts-docpage/) *(в том числе и иконки с содержимым)*

Например, создадим шаблон:

```
/* Шаблон иконки */
 var myIcon = ymaps.templateLayoutFactory.createClass('<div class="my_icon">' + 
            '{{ properties.iconCaption }}' + 
'</div>');
```

и затем, в `iconLayout` укажем этот шаблон:

```
...
iconLayout: myIcon,
iconImageSize: [32, 32],
iconImageOffset: [-5, -38], 
...
```

Небольшой пример: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/a11vbrw0/)

Comment: Спасибо, помогло. Я создал свой шаблон для метки и застилизовал его с помощью css.

Answer (score 0):

У яндекса для картинок есть необходимый инструмент с применением которого можно настроить марку, например:

```
MyIconContentLayout = ymaps.templateLayoutFactory.createClass(
       '<div class="some-class">$[properties.iconContent]</div>'), myPlacemark = new ymaps.Placemark(myMap.getCenter(), {
        iconContent: 'НАША МЕТКА',
       }, {
        iconLayout: 'default#imageWithContent',
        iconImageHref: '/images/some-icon.png',
        iconImageSize: [30, 30],
        iconContentOffset: [80, 30],
        iconContentLayout: MyIconContentLayout
    });
```

Движение осуществляется с помощью iconContentOffset, а стили применяются с помощью класса.